# Brightness problem NC110 (Samsung)

Tags: resolution, screen, brightness, samsung

**Translated into English**

Hello everyone.

It looks like I'm not the first person to have this problem, but since I'm new in the Ubuntu community, I don't know how to launch the terminal. There you have it; I have a NC110 (Samsung) and I'm not able to tweak the screen's brightness.

What are the steps to follow?

---

**Original question in French:**

Bonjour à tous.

Apparemment je ne suis pas le seul à avoir ce problème mais je suis tout nouveau dans la communauté ubuntu. Donc je ne sais pas comment accéder à la commande pour entrer les divers codes... 
Voilà, j'ai un NC110 (samsung) et je n'arrive pas à modifier la puissance de l'éclairage de l'écran.

Quelle est la marche à suivre?

Answer (score 2):

We cannot test this due to lack of harware but it seems that the updated [Voria Tools](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa) >2.0 support brightness control on NC110 (see [this post on Voria forums](http://www.voria.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=974&p=5608&hilit=NC110#p5608)). You can install the Voria tools by adding the following ppa to your sources:

```
ppa:voria/ppa
```

Please also read: [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)